# Javascript: test whether a string is a regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a user-created string which is to be used as a regular expression. How can I test the validity of this string?

My first thought was to use a regular expression to test this, but, thinking about it, the regular expression syntax itself is not a regular language, so this doesn't work.

My second thought was to attempt to create a [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) object using the string. However, the documentation does not mention what should happen when the string is an invalid regular expression.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Try using an invalid regular expressions and see what happens. Then take it from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `try/catch` to determine whether given string is able to create a valid `RegExp` object or not:

```
s = "(abc"; // invalid input regex string
valid = false;
try {
   new RegExp(s);
   valid = true; // reached here regex is valid
} catch(ex) {}

console.log(valid); // false
```

Comment: Thanks. I found [the specification that describes this behavior](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.4.1), which is what I was looking for.